# Kotlin: Skipping Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I playing around with Kotlin and Coroutines in my demo android application.

Here's what I have:

```
fun testCoroutine3() = runBlocking {
    var num = 0
    val jobs = List(10_000) { // create a lot of coroutines and list their jobs.
        launch(CommonPool) {
            delay(1000L)
            println(num++)
        }
    }

    for(job in jobs) {
        job.join() //wait for all jobs to finish
    }
    println("FINAL RESULT $num")
}
```

Basically I'm creating a list of 10,000 Coroutines that wait for 1 second and print a number then increment it.

Then when all jobs are done I print the final result.

(This demo is taken from the [GitHub Documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#coroutines-are-light-weight))

Now most of my test run fine, all the coroutines run almost simultaneously, and my final result is 10000

[image: Log showing Final Result = 10,000]

However in some rare occasions, I am getting the final result as 9,999

[image: Log showing Final Result = 9,999]

This become more obvious when I increase the number to 50,000 for example:

[image: Log showing Final Result = 49,998]

Is it possible that Kotlin is skipping some coroutines when there's a lot of them? on the 50,000, looks like it skipped 2

Or is something else happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`num++` consists of two operations: `tmp = num + 1` and `num = tmp`. When dealing with multithreading like your example there are cases where some operations might overwrite the results of another thread, leading to cases like your example.

If you want to know more, research "race conditions" where the end result depends on a "race" between two seperate processes.

Comment: Ah this makes a lot of sense! Any idea which approach I can use to make sure that I get Final result = 10,000? Other than just doing jobs.count

Comment: Only way to guarentee that is to either synchronize access to the variable or use the `Atomic*` classes to make sure each operation ends up being registered.

Comment: @Youssef Usually, you try to avoid using any shared mutable state at all. That will also eliminate this problem.

Comment: @marstran I agree that the design should move away from this, but in case we want to use it I found I can use AtomicInteger() instead.